# Conditional execution based on input string's prefix

Tags: java, strings

I have this method that basically takes a string and does different things
depending on what the string starts with. Is there a cleaner way to write this method?

```
public String analyze(BotMessage message)
{

    String lcmsg = message.message().toLowerCase();
    //Not a command
    if(!lcmsg.startsWith("!")) return "-1";

    //Message from whatever
     if(lcmsg.startsWith("!ping")) return "pong!";
     if(lcmsg.startsWith("!tournament")) return tournament(message);


     //message from skype
     if(message.skype())
     {
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!settournament")) return settournament(message);
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!promote")) return promote(message);
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!checkin")) return checkin(message);
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!checkout")) return checkout(message);
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!checkedin")) return checkedin(message);
         if(lcmsg.startsWith("!updatetournament")) return updatetournament();

     }

    return "-1";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like too much the fact that you use a `String` as the returned type of your function.

What about using a class hierarchy or exceptions?

I see opportunities to create a hierarchy even for the messages. Why don't you create a `BotMessage` and a `SkypeMessage`?

Both should have the logic to decide what to do in the base case, maybe in an `analyze` method. The `analyze` method of the `SkypeMessage` should, in addition, manage the Skype-specific aspects.

Finally you should simplify the code and remove the list of if statements.
Introduce a new set of objects to parse the messages. These objects should have a `match` method that check whether the string matches with their definition, and a `performAction` method that generates the return value.

Comment: I like the idea of creating new classes to handle the commands because what I really want is it get rid of those nasty if-statements. As for the return type it wouldn't really help in this scenario to change it because of how the rest of the application works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observer/Observable pattern for the `if(message.skipe(){..}` area.

So each each observer evaluate the `if` and run the method (the methods are wrote inside the Observer).

If a new test is needed, you have just to had a new Observer with no impact on other Observers.

Many useful patterns are very clearly explained in O'Reilly "Head First Design Patterns"  book.

Comment: The problem is that the class already is Observable so I feel it would just add confusion to make it an Observer aswell(if even possible).

Comment: @warbio no it is not a problem : for Java it is powerful to be an `observer observable` for managing nested/complex logical choices. To help maintenance you can put observers in a sub-package of observable, so hierarchy is visible at the first glance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I managed to rewrite the method following @mariosangiorgio advice.
I made a Command interface and gave each command a own class.

```
public String analyze(Message message)
{       
    //Not a command
    if(!message.getMessage().startsWith("!")) return "-1";

    for(Command cmd : commands)
    {
        if(cmd.Match(message)) return cmd.preformAction(message);
    }

    return "-1";
}
```

Comment: Returning `"-1"` still falls into the "stringly typed" antipattern.